# Not sure how to update State in Redux properly

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, flux

I am not sure how to update the `state` properly in `redux`. I get duplicated entries.

Thats how the `state` looks like

```
const STATE = {
    windowOne: { ... }
    windwoTwo: { ... }
    windowThree: { ... }
}
```

That is one of my reducers

```
export default function reducer(state = STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case type.WINDOW_ONE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                windowOne: {
                    ...state.windowOne,
                    foo: action.bar,
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I map the state like to the props of my component

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(combinedActions, dispatch);
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const { windowOne } = state.windowOne;

    return {
        windowOne,
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SomeComponent);
```

And I combine the various reducers here

```
export default combineReducers({
    windowOne,
    windowTwo,
    windowThree
});
```

When I use `redux-logger`, I see that in `windowOne` the whole `state` is copied. In there, after triggering an `action`, I find `windowTwo` and `windowThree`. I am also not sure why I have to specify `windowOne` in these lines

```
    const { windowOne } = state.windowOne;
```

Shouldn't `const { windowOne } = state` be enough? That might be related...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) for `combineReducers`; it takes care of sending to each reducer the appropriate slice of the state and merging the results. For the reducer shown, this means you should pass it the initial state for `windowOne` only and return just the updated state for `windowOne`:

```
export default function reducer(state = STATE.windowOne, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case type.WINDOW_ONE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                foo: action.bar,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After this, `const { windowOne } = state` in `mapStateToProps` should work. Also note that you'll need a default case in each reducer, as all reducers receive all actions, and that `STATE` might be more appropriately named `initialState`.

Comment: Hm, I had it this way before. But I changed it to the code I wrote because I need to exchange data between `windowOne`, `windowTwo` and `windowThree`. I thought I pass my `reducer` the whole `STATE`  and then only return the `windowOne` part. That updates the `state` and the newly created data is accessible in another `reducer` where I also pass `STATE`. with `STATE.windowOne`, I though, I should be able to access the updated data?!

Comment: If you use `combineReducers`, passing in and returning the entire state will create a nested copy in each top-level state property. You'll probably want to either use a single reducer or use a package like `reduce-reducers`, as explained in [Beyond combineReducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.html#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers).